# loop through the error message bags and then create a new array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to loop through the error message bag ($validator->errors()->getMessages()) array and push its objects to another array ($error)

```
$error = array();
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'username' => 'required|unique:User',
    'password' => 'required',
    'fullname' => 'required|unique:Profile',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:Profile'
]);

if($validator->fails()) :
    foreach($validator->errors()->getMessages() as $m => $key):
        array_push($error,$key);
    endforeach;
endif;
```

and then loop unto the new array ($error) and create a string base on the new array objects ($str)

```
$str = '<ul class="c_red padding_zero margin_zero menu">';
foreach($error as $e ){ // this is the line 113
    $str.= '<li>'.$e.'</li>';
}
$str.='</ul>';

return array('success' => false,  'message' => $error );
```

but it returns me an error

> Array to string conversion line 113

here's the response when not loop to $error array to create $str string

> {"success":false,"message":[["The username field is required."],["The password > field is required."],["The fullname field is required."],["The email field is > required."]]}

Comment: May be `'<li>'.$e.'</li>'` `$e` is Array Here... Just an guess..

Comment: Please see my updated post, I included there the response when not looping to $error array to create $str

Answer (score 5, accepted):

each key in the errors may contains more then one error so it will be a string...

so you could do this:

```
if($validator->fails()) :
    foreach($validator->errors()->getMessages() as $validationErrors):
        if (is_array($validationErrors)) {
            foreach($validationErrors as $validationError):
                $error[] = $validationError;
            endforeach;
        } else {
            $error[] = $validationErrors;
        }
    endforeach;
endif;
```

here you will get an array of all error messages...